# Dockerfile ADD or COPY multiple files in different subdirectories in a single step, keeping directory structure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's suppose I have an Elixir project tree organized like this:

```
$ tree .
.
├── apps
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── mix.exs
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── mix.exs
│   └── c
│       ├── ...
│       └── mix.exs
├── mix.exs
└── mix.lock
```

(unrelated files dropped)

The Dockerfile I wrote for this project looks roughly like this:

```
FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix:latest

ENV MIX_ENV=prod

# Elixir deps
# FIXME: do not hardcode apps/ subdirectories, use wildcards somehow
# FIXME: copy everything in one step somehow
ADD apps/a/mix.exs apps/a/
ADD apps/b/mix.exs apps/b/
ADD apps/c/mix.exs apps/c/
ADD mix.exs mix.lock ./
RUN mix local.hex --force && mix deps.get && mix deps.compile

<skipped>

ADD . .
RUN mix compile && mix phx.digest

CMD [ "mix", "phx.server" ]
```

Is there a way to ADD or COPY all the `apps/*/mix.exs` in a single step, preserving their directory structure (so that each `apps/foo/mix.exs` ends up in `$WORKDIR/apps/foo/mix.exs`)?

To the best of my knowledge, there is no obvious way to do what I want. E. g. saying something like `ADD apps/*/mix.exs mix.exs mix.lock ./` just copies everything into the WORKDIR (and the files overwrite each other).

Maybe there is some non-obvious way?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I could think of is to add the following in the `.dockerignore` file

```
apps/**
!apps/*/mix.exs
```

and in the dockerfile,

```
COPY apps/ /apps
COPY mix.exs mix.lock /
```

or even

```
COPY . /
```

NOTE

If you don't have to stick to pure dockerfile solution, wrap your `docker build` in a shell script or makefile and use `cp` is also a good way to do it.

Comment: That won't work, because later in the Dockerfile I still have to ADD/COPY the whole project tree (`ADD . .`).